# Tree of templates to generate UI layout from structure saved in Database

Tags: mysql, templates, tree

Help me please with such problem:

I want to generate dynamically View object based on mysql tree.
For example there are two tables which defines all views and it's variables:
[image]
What structure of table 'template' I must to create to be possible to do:

1. Generate tree structure of UI layout from 'template' table, which based on some view from table 'view'
2. Each property(variable) template can be also a reference to another template
3. Each template can be extended with another and some variables can be reassigned with other value:
   [image]

Comment: regarding your question: you might look into term "closure tables" (it's also covered in 2nd chapter of "SQL Antipatterns" book).

Comment: I understand this, but.. All my tries ends with structures which have not strong constraints of values to view variable. I can add that constraints by using of triggers, but I think that it's very far from perfect solution.
template_table(id, parent_id, fk_view_id, fk_var_id, val) - without triggers I can insert the row where fk_view_id = 1 and fk_var_id == 10 (what reale references to view_id == 4) and so on. Hope somebody helps with "template builder" with more correct structure